# Как добавить и удалить класс при нажатии на ссылку

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код навигационного бара со списком с ссылками ведущими на `id` блока, и блоки с содержимым страниц. Как реализовать чтобы при нажатии на ссылку, элементу списка присваивался класс `.active`, а у блока с `id` на который ведет ссылка удалялся класс `.hidden` при этом всем остальным блокам с классом `.page` этот класс присваивался.

```
<div class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#home">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page1">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page2">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page3">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page4">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="home" class="page">
    страница с содержимым home
</div>
<div id="page1" class="page hidden">
    страница с содержимым page1
</div>
<div id="page2" class="page hidden">
    страница с содержимым page2
</div>
<div id="page3" class="page hidden">
    страница с содержимым page3
</div>
<div id="page4" class="page hidden">
    страница с содержимым page4
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По клику на ссылку у всех `<li>` в `.nav` убирается класс `.active`, а у её родителю он добавляется.
Затем берётся `href` ссылки и используется в качестве селектора для поиска соответствующего блока.
Всем блокам-страницам добавляется класс `hidden`, после чего у выбранного блока этот класс убирается.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $pages = $('.page');
    var $links = $('.nav li');
    $('.nav a').on("click", function() {
        $links.removeClass("active");
        $(this).parent().addClass("active");
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $pages.addClass("hidden");
        $(href).removeClass("hidden");
    });
});
```

```css
.active {
    background-color: gray;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#home">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page1">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page2">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page3">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#page4">Something else here</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="home" class="page">
    страница с содержимым home
</div>
<div id="page1" class="page hidden">
    страница с содержимым page1
</div>
<div id="page2" class="page hidden">
    страница с содержимым page2
</div>
<div id="page3" class="page hidden">
    страница с содержимым page3
</div>
<div id="page4" class="page hidden">
    страница с содержимым page4
</div>
```

Comment: у тебя постепенно все li будут активными :-)

Comment: @Grundy ага. И это неспроста: в описании автора нет ни слова про удаление класса `active` с других `<li>`. Поэтому я сделал всё равно так, как написано :)

Comment: У него зато есть: скрывать неактивные, а сейчас получается - li активны, а див скрыт :)

Comment: Да совсем забыл сказать чтобы класс .active удалялся у li. Но в принципе то не проблема, сам допишу. А это как раз то что нужно, спасибо большое)

Comment: @seledkapod на здоровье. Я доработал ответ. Если он вас устраивает, не забудьте отметить его как правильный.

Comment: @Regent эмм я недавно здесь, что-то не могу найти как его отметить((

Comment: @seledkapod с помощью галочки, слева от верха ответа. Собственно, вы её уже поставили.